# Qt- How to merge four images in single rounded image

Tags: c++, image, qt, qpainter, qimage

I tried to show avatar image in rounded form. it was working good.

```
QImage image(":/images/person1.png");

if (image.width() != CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M ||
        image.height() != CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M)
    image = image.scaled(QSize(CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M ),
                         Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

QImage roundedImage(CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M, CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

roundedImage.fill(Qt::transparent);

QBrush brush(image);
QPainter painter(&roundedImage);
QPen pen(QColor(176, 216, 242), 1);

painter.setPen(pen);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.setBrush(brush);
painter.drawEllipse(1.0, 1.0, CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M - 2, CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M - 2);

m_defaultAvatar = QPixmap::fromImage(roundedImage);
```

*AVATAR_WIDTH_M* & *AVATAR_HEIGHT_M* are public variables.
 Here what is result of this lines:
[image]
Now , I want to change it to rounded image with merging four photos. I've changed this line

```
    image.height() != CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M)
image = image.scaled(QSize(CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M ),
                     Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

To this:

```
   image.height() != CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M)
image = image.scaled(QSize(CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M / 2, CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M /2),
                     Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

And result is :
[image]
It was good for me but it's not enough. target is using four different images in this rounded avatar instead of single image. How to change above codes to merge 
   **QImage image(":/images/person1.png");

and 

   QImage image2(":/images/person2.png");

and 

   QImage image(":/images/person3.png");

and

   QImage image4(":/images/person4.png");**

Comment: use painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Exclusion);

Answer (score 0):

Why not merging the four images first and then rounding the merged image?

```
// Create the merged image
QImage mergedImage(2*AVATAR_WIDTH_M, AVATAR_HEIGHT_M ,QImage::Format_RGB32);
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&combinedImage);
painter.drawImage(0, 0, image.scaled(AVATAR_WIDTH_M,AVATAR_HEIGHT_M));
painter.drawImage(AVATAR_WIDTH_M, 0, image2.scaled(AVATAR_WIDTH_M,AVATAR_HEIGHT_M));
painter.drawImage(0, AVATAR_HEIGHT_M, image3.scaled(AVATAR_WIDTH_M,AVATAR_HEIGHT_M));
painter.drawImage(AVATAR_WIDTH_M, AVATAR_HEIGHT_M, image4.scaled(AVATAR_WIDTH_M,AVATAR_HEIGHT_M));
    painter.end();

// Round the merged image...
```